# Is there an extension of Ogg's results to surfaces of Genus 1

Tags: riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds, teichmuller-theory, orbifolds, monster

The first hints of moonshine appeared around 1974 when Andrew Ogg noticed that quotienting the hyperbolic plane by normalizers of the Hecke Congruence subgroups $\Gamma_{0}(p)$ has genus zero iff p is a divisor of the order of the monster group.

A natural question then to ask is can we try to extend the result to genus 1? That is:

1. For which $p$ is the quotient of the hyperbolic plane by the normalizer $\Gamma_{0}(p)$ of genus 1?
2. If its finite, does that set of $p$ divide anything interesting?
3. If its infinite, does that sequence of $p$'s divide some other interesting sequence?

Has there been any prior work on (1)?

Comment: Agreed the teichmuller theory tag might be misplaced but I learned first of quotienting surfaces in a teichmuller theory textbook so i figured adding it would attract the right audience. Feel free to remove and replace with something more relevant.

Comment: Do you mean to quotient by the normalizer rather than $\Gamma_0(p)$ itself in "1."?

Comment: Yes, I’m editing that